# Function Graph | Range

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

The function Graph is

[image]

This was one of the questions, I was assigned, in my pre-calculus class. We were supposed to write the Interval Notation for the Graph's Domain and Range.

So the range, as is visible is,

> [-5,4)

but I used a decomposed one,

> [-5,-3] U [-3,4)

and it wasn't graded. Why is the latter one wrong? I read through everyone I could find, they both result in the same sets, is there something i'm still not seeing? Are you only supposed to use the simplest/most precise notation when it comes to function graphs?

(NOTE: the point (-5,4) isn't filled, it's an open interval)

Comment: Those two sets are identical. This is a question for your professor, not stack exchange.

Comment: The latter one isn't wrong, but another (more complicated) way of writing the same thing. Simplicity is not a strict requirement anywhere in mathematics, but writing things as simply as possible is a useful skill, and certain educators will award marks based on simplicity. You should ask your teacher why they didn't mark it correct.

Comment: I did try asking him, he just wasn't willing to listen, so i thought i'd bring this up here, and get some actual help. Thank you so much! This had me scratching my head for a while lol